# Com armazenar e recuperar data nesse formato?

Tags: mysql, asp

Qual é a melhor forma de armazenar e recuperar data nesse formato, em MYSQL?

```
<news:publication_date>2019-02-19T18:57:26-03:00</news:publication_date>
```

Comment: Você quer que retorne ajustando a `timezone` ou desconsiderando?

Comment: Fiz uma gambiarra, estou convertendo para string e concatenado as datas com horário, e colocando o fuso estático, já que é sempre o mesmo.